# Is $SO_2(\mathbb{C})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C^{\times}}$?

Tags: group-theory

$SO_2(\mathbb{C})=\{ A \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \mid A A ^T = I, \det(A)=1 \}$

Let $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}  \in SO_2(\mathbb C)$, and we have that:

$$a^2+b^2=1,~c^2+d^2=1,~ ad-bc =1$$

By solving this we have

$$SO_2(\mathbb C)=\{ \begin{pmatrix} \sin z & -\cos z \\ \cos z & \sin z \end{pmatrix} \mid z\in \mathbb C \}$$

Now how do I define $f: \mathbb C^{\times} \to SO_2(\mathbb C)$ such that it is a isomorphism?

Note: $e^{iz} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \sin z & -\cos z \\ \cos z & \sin z \end{pmatrix}$ is an isomorphism for $\mathbb S^1=\{\ z \in \mathbb C \mid |z|=1\} \cong SO_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Can I extend it from $\mathbb S^1$ to $\mathbb C^\times$?

Comment: Isn't the definition you give at the beginning the definition of $S{\color{red}U}_2(\mathbb{C})$, the [special **unitary** group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group)? $SU(2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$, while $SO_2(\mathbb{C})$ (the special orthogonal group, defined by the relation $AA^T = I$ without conjugation) is indeed homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ as far as I remember.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In the question they define $SO_2(\mathbb{C})=\{ A \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \mid A  A ^t = I, \det(A)=1 \}$ and I remember small $t$ means transpose with conjugation.

Comment: Usually it's the dagger $\dagger$ that represents transpose with conjugation (as in $A^\dagger$), and it does look like a small $t$. But $SO$ is defined without taking the conjugate.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes,  indeed it is 1D. So it can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb C^\times$. So I much have done something wrong.

Comment: Hi, please always include some English words in the question title, so that on right-clicks, the browser's context menu is not overridden by the MathJax menu.